# Android emulator does not show image stored

Tags: java, android, xml, android-emulator, android-camera2

I'm working on a project designed to turn a smartphone into a Microscope (little bit of image processing too); I've decided to build my program in Android Studio for android phones.

Looking online I found a few tutorials on how to access the camera, capture an image and store it in memory. For some reason the emulator used to run the program is showing is only capturing the image, but not storing it in memory. Is their an issue with the emulator? How would I transfer this program I'm writing to my Android Google Nexus 5 phone?

here is some XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.smartphonemicroscope">
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2"></uses-feature> <!-- Acess camera2 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Microscope">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

here is some Java:

```
package com.example.user.smartphonemicroscope;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraDevice;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import java.io.File;

public class Microscope extends Activity {
Button button;
ImageView imageView;
static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_microscope);
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent camera_intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            File file = getFile();
            camera_intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
            startActivityForResult(camera_intent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

private File getFile() {

    File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");

    if(!folder.exists())
    {
        folder.mkdir();
    }

    File image_file = new File(folder,"cam_image.jpg");

    return image_file;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    String path = "sdcard/camera_app/cam_image.jpg";
    imageView.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
  }
}
```

I also have a few images of what it looks like in the interface.

[Emulator Camera Accessed, after pressing capture button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cph8B.jpg)
[Image Captured, but will not save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSFNb.jpg)

Comment: To test on your physical hardware just plug your phone into your PC with USB debugging enabled and in android studio select your hardware when prompted for a device. Also check out CommonWares answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File folder = new File("sdcard/camera_app");
```

That value is wrong on ~1.5 billion Android devices.

More generally, **never hardcode paths**. Always use some method to derive a root location to write into. You appear to be wishing to write to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html). In that case, use a method like `getExternalFilesDir()` (on `Context`) or methods on `Environment` to get a root location to write to.

Comment: Thanks so much for answering my question.